# How to count number of patterns using variables in tr/// operator?

Tags: perl, variables, tr

I want to count the number of occurrences of nucleotides (the letters 'A, T, G, C' in a string). I was trying to use the `tr///` operator for this, but it returns a count of zero every time in the below code.

This only happens if I use a variable inside the `tr///` operator. If I type the individual letters separately it works. I wanted to know if we could use variables inside `tr///` operator for pattern matching (and counting). And if we can, someone tell me how to modify my code.

Later I plan to count the number of codons (~64). Hence the trouble. Appreciate your time. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $orf = "ATGCTAGCTAGCATAGAGCTAGCTA";
my @atgc = qw(A T G C);
my %hash = ();

foreach my $nt(@atgc) {
  $hash{$nt} = ($orf =~ tr/$nt//);
}
```

Comment: The `tr///` operator works on a character-by-character basis. It won't help you when you want to count codons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$hash{$nt} = eval "\$orf =~ tr/\Q$nt\E//"
```

should do the job. Maybe this is not the most effective solution though.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Can you tell me why you used a backslash in front of $orf?

Comment: To obtain a valid Perl code after the interpolation of a double quoted string.

Answer (score 4):

There is no instance of "`$`", "`n`" or "`t`" in "`ATGCTAGCTAGCATAGAGCTAGCTA`", thus `tr` correctly returns zero.

If you want to build a `tr///` operator, you'll need to parse and compile it.

```
my %counts;
for my $nt (@atgc) {
   $counts{$nt} = eval "\$orf =~ tr/\Q$nt\E//";
}
```

But I wouldn't use `tr///`.

```
my %atgc = map { $_ => 1 } @atgc;
my %counts;
++$counts{$nt} for grep $atgc{$_}, split //, $orf;
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Perl won't interpolate a variable into the search list for `tr///`. You will have to use a regular expression instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $orf = "ATGCTAGCTAGCATAGAGCTAGCTA";
my @atgc = qw(A T G C);
my %count;

$count{$1}++ while $orf =~ /([@atgc])/g;

printf "%s => %d\n", $_, $count{$_} for @atgc;
```

**output**

```
A => 8
T => 6
G => 6
C => 5
```

---

**Beware**

This isn't - as it may appear - a general solution for matching any one of an array of strings. What is happening is `@atcg` is being interpolated into the regex as if it was in a *double-quoted string*. That means Perl will use the `$"` built-in variable (set to a single space by default) to turn it into a string equivalent to `join $", @atgc`.

So the code actually looks like

```
$count{$1}++ while $orf =~ /([A T G C])/g;
```

which will match spaces as well as the letters, and may break altogether if `@atgc` contains anything that is special inside a regex character class like `^`, `]` or `-`.

Counting spaces unnecessarily shouldn't be a problem, but if your list may contain symbols then this isn't a solution you should be using.

A count for every ASCII character can be written safely as

```
$count{$1}++ while $orf =~ /(.)/sg;
```

and the unwanted information in the `%count` hash can simply be ignored.

Comment: That will also count spaces in the input. That canl mess up if you have "`^`", `"`]" or "`-`" in `@atgc`.

Comment: When I use the code, I actually get everything in multiples of 4.

Comment: @Anish: you should replace your entire `foreach` loop with that line of code. My solution stands on its own. I have updated my answer to show this more clearly.

Comment: @ikegami: I was aware of that, and I think it is fine for this particular situation. But I have added a caveat for others who may be looking for a solution to a sililar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `s///g`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $orf = "ATGCTAGCTAGCATAGAGCTAGCTA";
my @atgc = qw(A T G C);

my %hash = map {$_ => $orf =~ s/$_/$_/g } @atgc;
```

Output:

```
---
A: 8
C: 5
G: 6
T: 6
```

If the source string is going to be really long, you can treat it as holding the contents of a while and read one byte at a time assuming the characters are guaranteed to be ASCII.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $orf = "ATGCTAGCTAGCATAGAGCTAGCTA";
my %atgc = map { $_ => undef } qw(A T G C);

use YAML;
print Dump count(\$orf, \%atgc);

sub count {
    my $src_ref = shift;
    my $lookup = shift;

    my %count;

    open my $src, '<', $src_ref or die $!;
    {
        local $/ = \1;
        exists $lookup->{$_} and $count{ $_ } += 1 while <$src>;
    }
    close $src;

    return \%count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions etc. to do this, you just need to walk a string:

```
my $orf = "ATGCTAGCTAGCATAGAGCTAGCTA";
my %nt;

$nt{$_}++ foreach (split('', $orf));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a pattern compiler.

```
sub make_counter {
  my @sequences = @_;

  my $pattern = "(?:" . join("|", map quotemeta, @sequences) . ")";

  my $compiled = eval q<
    sub {
      local($_) = @_;
      my $n = () = /$pattern/g;
    }
  >;

  if (defined $compiled) {
    return $compiled;
  }
  else {
    die "$0: internal: counter compilation failed:\n$@\n";
  }
}
```

With [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), we force all characters in the sequence to match themselves only with no special meanings. [Section 4 of the Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string?) describes that funky bit for counting matches:

> Another version uses a global match in list context, then assigns the result to a scalar, producing a count of the number of matches.
>
> ```
> $count = () = $string =~ /-\d+/g;
> ```

Note that it tolerates junk in your sequence. For example, count nucleotides with

```
my @nucleotides = qw/ G A T C /;

my $numnuc = make_counter @nucleotides;
print $numnuc->("xGxAxTxxxxTyA1C2A"), "\n";
```

Output:

```
7
```

Count codons with

```
my @codons = qw(
  TTT TCT TAT TGT TTC TCC TAC TGC TTA TCA TAA TGA
  TTG TCG TAG TGG CTT CCT CAT CGT CTC CCC CAC CGC
  CTA CCA CAA CGA CTG CCG CAG CGG ATT ACT AAT AGT
  ATC ACC AAC AGC ATA ACA AAA AGA ATG ACG AAG AGG
  GTT GCT GAT GGT GTC GCC GAC GGC GTA GCA GAA GGA
  GTG GCG GAG GGG
);

my $numcod = make_counter @codons;
print $numcod->("GAG-GGG!AGG,TAT#TTT");
```

Note that any junk, if present, must occur *between* codon sequences.

Output:

```
5
```